# Packages 404 not found

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I know there are many questions like this but this is not the same details. When I use `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get update` command in terminal, this is what I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
dell@dell-Inspiron-1420:~$
```

Those are my only problems. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what it says, this ppa doesn't have packages for trusty yet. You have to wait for the developers to release packages for trusty or try to install the saucy packages manually. See here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/ no trusty.

Comment: But i use `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `update`. And also it's running on terminal. I don't know how to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Trusty now, the ppa may change to trusty automatically. To prove this, you can select the ppa on software sources, edit, and look what binary is written there. If it is trusty and you can not change, than the sudo update and sudo upgrade will return what you experienced. I experienced this in trusty with desurium ppa. While I was able to switch the binary from 13.04 to 13.10 and vice versa in Ubuntu 13.10, I could not do it in trusty yet. Simply no other binary to choice except trusty, I do not know why. So temporary I have to abandon desurium ppa in trusty.